# how to configure a ssh key via script on the Jenkins EC2 Plugin?

Tags: jenkins, amazon-ec2, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

I have a Groovy script to configure a Cloud using the Jenkins EC2 Plugin. I'm able to configure all the parameters that I need except for the EC2 Key Pair's Private Key. I have an existing key that I want to use named /jnks/jenkins/dev/ec2-fleet/ssh-creds.

I already tried using the name/credential Id and pasting the SSH key value directly on the privateKey variable as the documentation without luck.

Expected Result:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nPSxw.png)